# Excel VBA: How to get input from user and compare exact match in column D?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Excel VBA: How to get input from user and compare exact match in column D if a match found highlight that found match  automatically in column D? Is it possible by using Excel 2013?

1. Get input from the user  if a exact match found in column D
   highlight that value in column D (value must be type Variant)
2. If no match found an alert msg(Not Found)
3. Wants to clear the input text box automatically for next user input

please help this will very helpful for me....

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: What have you done so far...

Comment: I'm new for programming that's why i'm seeking help from talented programming  peoples like  gizlmeier. Help me if u can don't criticize JFS

Answer (score 0):

By exact match you are talking about case sensitive matching, aren't you? If so this should do it:

```
Function findValue()

Dim Value As Variant
Dim Sheetname As String

Value = InputBox("Enter Value:", "Input")

Sheetname = "ENTER SHEETNAME HERE"

'Sheets(Sheetname).Columns("D:D").Select
Dim Cell As Variant

'Search in Column D | MatchCase True = case sensitive
Set Cell = Sheets(Sheetname).Columns("D:D").Find(What:=Value, After:=Sheets(Sheetname).Range("D1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not Cell Is Nothing Then

    'Value is found, Highlight Cell
    Sheets(Sheetname).Range(Cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else

    'Value Not found
    MsgBox "Not Found"
End If
End Function
```

Otherwise you have to change the MatchCase option to False

Comment: Thanks for your great help buddy.. and i got a run-time error type mismatch in line 13.. pls help to solve it  ... my sheet name is sheet1 cell address is full D column

Comment: This is weird, the code works fine for me. Could you give any more info of where exactly the code fails?

Comment: No you used it wrong, the Sheetname variable is for the name of your Worksheet, default Worksheet name is Sheet1 for Example

And the line inside the If (Sheets(Sheetname).Range(Cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 4) Should stay as it is, you may only change the ColorIndex

Comment: Oh what are the things i want to change in that code to make it work??? i'm very new for excel but its requires for my new job so pls help to solve it gizlmeier...

Comment: You could just tell me your Worksheet name and how the found cell should be highlighted and I modify the Code for you

Comment: gizlmeier Thanks For your Help And I'm Happy to inform you that i created an vba app in my own with your code as reference... :-)