# compare input text to cell and get row in external document

Tags: excel, vba, database

Form 1

I am getting the code to wire to the database file but the check   if the value from text box 2 is already in column B throw a message and exit is not working Also if the database is open I am not getting an error it just freezes.

Form 2

I am getting the spinning wheel. It is how it is supposed to work is if textbox1 value is already in column B add time data to column F of that row if it is textbox 1 value is not found in B throw a massage

Any help is appreciated

FORM 1 CODE

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'check to see is all data is filled in
    If TextBox1.Value = "" Or TextBox2.Value = "" Or _
       TextBox3.Value = "" Or TextBox4.Value = "" Or TextBox5.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "YOU DID NOT FILL IN ALL THE INFO."
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Call Submit_Data
    Call resetForm
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub resetForm()
    TextBox1.Value = ""
    TextBox2.Value = ""
    TextBox3.Value = ""
    TextBox4.Value = ""
    TextBox5.Value = ""
    UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
        
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
        
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
        
End Sub
        
Sub Submit_Data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         
    Dim App As New Excel.Application
    Dim wBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim iRow As Long
         
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.xlsm"
         
    'Check File Exist or Not
    'If Dir(FileName) = "" Then
         'MsgBox "Database File is missing. Unable to proceed.", vbOKOnly vbCritical, "Error"
            
         'Exit Sub
     'End If
         
     Set wBook = App.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
     App.Visible = False
         
     If wBook.ReadOnly = True Then
         MsgBox "Database is in use. Please try after sometimes.", vbookonly + vbCritical, "error"
         Exit Sub
     End If
         
     'Transfer the Data
     id = TextBox2.Value
     With wBook.Sheets("test")
         Set ws = wBook.Sheets("test")
         m = Application.Match(id, ws.Columns("B"), 0)      'try to match an existing row
            
         If IsError(m) Then                                  'no match?
             iRow = .Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
             .Range("A" & iRow).Value = TextBox1.Value 'Cell
             .Range("B" & iRow).Value = TextBox2.Value   'workorder number
             .Range("C" & iRow).Value = TextBox3.Value   'product number
             .Range("D" & iRow).Value = TextBox4.Value    'Work order quanity
             .Range("E" & iRow).Value = Date  'date
             .Range("F" & iRow).Value = Time   'time
             .Range("M" & iRow).Value = TextBox5.Value   'crew size
          Else
              MsgBox "JOB ALREADY CLOCKED IN!"
              Exit Sub
           End If
       End With
         
       wBook.Close Savechanges:=True
       App.Quit
         
       Set App = Nothing
         
       'Reset the form
       Call resetForm
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       MsgBox "Data submitted successfully!"
End Sub
```

FORM 2 CODE

```vb
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        'check to see is all data is filled in
        
        If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "YOU DID NOT ENTER WO."
            
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        
        
        Call Submit_Data
        
        Call resetForm
        Unload Me
        
        
        End Sub
        
        
        Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        Unload Me
        End Sub
        
        Sub Submit_Data()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         
        Dim App As New Excel.Application
        Dim wBook As Excel.Workbook
         
        Dim FileName As String
         
        Dim iRow As Long
         
        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.xlsm"
         
        'Check File Exist or Not
         
        'If Dir(FileName) = "" Then
         
            'MsgBox "Database File is missing. Unable to proceed.", vbOKOnly vbCritical, "Error"
            
            'Exit Sub
         
        'End If
         
        Set wBook = App.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
         
        App.Visible = False
         
        If wBook.ReadOnly = True Then
            MsgBox "Database is in use. Please try after sometimes.", vbookonly + vbCritical, "error"
            
            Exit Sub
        End If
         
        'Transfer the Data
         
        id = TextBox1.Value
         
        With wBook.Sheets("Database")
         
            
            m = Application.Match(id, ("B"), 0)       'try to match an existing row
            
            If IsError(m) Then                                  'no match?
               
                
                 MsgBox "NEVER CLOCKED IN"
                 
                Exit Sub
                
        End If
            
                With ws.Rows(m)
                
                .Columns("F").Value = Time
                
          wBook.Close Savechanges:=True
         
        App.Quit
         
        Set App = Nothing
         
        'Reset the form
         
        Call resetForm
         
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
         
        MsgBox "Data submitted successfully!"
            
              End With
            
            
                
          End With
            
        End Sub
        
        
               
         Sub resetForm()
        
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus
        
        
        End Sub
            
           
        Private Sub UserForm_Click()
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: In Form1 when you `Exit Sub` if the id already exists, you're leaving the workbook and the Excel instance still open...  That will lock the workbook for any later updates.

Comment: When posting code, please *indent* it, and don't double/triple-space the lines, or it's difficult to review without a whole lot of scrolling up and down.

Comment: I can see that now and can fix that but it never gets their even if Id exists it still adds to the sheet

Comment: In form2 the Match line is wrong - compare to same line in form 1 code

Comment: The one in  form 1 does not work so am I am matching it to what is in form 2?

Comment: There's no need to create a second instance of Excel to open the database file - you can open it in the same instance where your code is running.  If the database file can remain open between records then you only need to open it if it's not already open.  The `Match()` in the first code looks OK to me

Comment: I just checked again and it does not work. It is always adding in to the file even if already in there.

Comment: I am getting an 2042 error for variable m every time

Comment: m = Application.Match(TextBox2.Value, 5, 0) even when I put 5 in text box2 I still get not recognizing a match

Comment: Match expects a range or an array as the second argument, so you can't do what you're trying.  It would need to be something like `Application.Match("5",Array(5),0)`, but that *also* doesn't match, because "5" (a string from a textbox) doesn't match the number 5.  Convert your textbox entry to a Long and then perform the match against the worksheet column (assuming that contains numeric values)

Answer (score 1):

If the ID values on your "database" sheet are numeric, you need to use a numeric input for `Match()`, so:

```vb
'Transfer the Data
     id = CLng(TextBox2.Value)  '<<< assuming the value is numeric: may want to add a check...
     With wBook.Sheets("test")
         Set ws = wBook.Sheets("test")
         m = Application.Match(id, ws.Columns("B"), 0)      'try to match an existing row
            
         If IsError(m) Then                                  'no match?
             iRow = .Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
             'etc
             'etc
```

You don't need a separate instance of Excel to save the record - it's better to just open the file in the existing instance.

Also - if you're planning on not closing the file immediately after populating the data row, you need to check to see if it's already open when you perform the next save: opening a file which is already open can give unexpected results.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262538/478884

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I figured it out I had to define m as Long

Comment: `m` needs to be a `Variant`, otherwise you'll get a runtime error if there's no match (because the Error value can't be assigned to `m` if it's declared as `Long`)